# Problem: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'roles')

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a kick command (following reconlx's Kick, Ban, and Unban command tutorial). All commands stop working (including the kick command).

If anyone can take a look, it'd be helpful.

Code for `kick.js` and the error is down below.

```
const { MessageEmbed, Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'Kicks a member',
    userPermissions: ["KICK_MEMBERS"],
    options: [
        {
            name: "member",
            description: "The member you wish to kick",
            type: "USER",
            required: true
        },
        {
            name: "reason",
            description: "Reason for kicking",
            type: "STRING",
            required: false
        },
    ],

    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {String[]} args
     */

    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        const target = interaction.options.getMember("target");
        const reason = 
            interaction.options.getString("reason") || "No reason(s) provided";
        
        const rolePositionCheck = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("You can't kick a person with a higher role than yours!")
            .setFooter({ text: "Error: Lower Role Position"})

        if (
            target.roles.highest.position >= 
            interaction.member.roles.highest.position
        )
            return interaction.followUp({ 
                embeds: 
                    [rolePositionCheck],
            });
        
        // Message which is sent to the person kicked
        const kickMessage = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`You've been kicked from ${interaction.guild.name}`)
            .setFooter({ text: `Reason: ${reason}` })
        
        await target.send({ embeds: [kickMessage] });
        
        // The action of kicking, along with the reason
        target.kick(reason)
        
        // Message which is sent to the mod who kicked.
        const kickAftermath = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(`${target.user.tag} has been kicked!`)
            .setFooter({ text: `${reason}` })

        interaction.followUp({ 
            embeds: 
                [kickAftermath], 
        });
    },

};
```

Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'roles')
at Object.run (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Tonkotsu\SlashCommands\moderation\kick.js:38:20)
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Tonkotsu\events\interactionCreate.js:27:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Looks like a typo, you're using `options.getMember("target")` while the option `name: "member"`. That's why `target` is null. Try `options.getMember("member")`

Comment: It works! Thanks man, appreciate the help.